# Callback function not executing second statement - C++ MQTT

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I've programmed a callback function that handles MQTT messages (payload). I want to switch of pins not based on an incoming payload. The problem I have now is that the first statement is executed nicely when sending 11. However the second statement is not working. Strangely when I send two messages one containing 1x and the other x1 I can again toggle both pins. It's a very strange problem!
Could anyone help me with this, thanks very much. I'm using the PubSubClient library.

```
 void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
      Serial.print("Message arrived [");
      Serial.print(topic);
      Serial.print("] ");
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
      }

       //Set GPIO0 to HIGH or LOW on first character received in message
      if (payload[0] == '1') {
        digitalWrite(GPIO0, HIGH);   // Turn the relay on
        client.publish(getOutTopic().c_str(), "GPIO0 set to HIGH");
      } else if (payload[0] == '0') {
        digitalWrite(GPIO0, LOW);  // Turn the relay off
        client.publish(getOutTopic().c_str(), "GPIO0 set to LOW");
      }

      //Set GPIO2 to HIGH or LOW on first character received in message
      if (payload[1] == '1') {
        digitalWrite(GPIO2, HIGH);   // turn LED off. With High it is inactive  on the ESP-01)
        client.publish(getOutTopic().c_str(), "GPIO2 set to HIGH");
      } else if (payload[1] == '0') {
        digitalWrite(GPIO2, LOW);  // Turn the LED on by making the voltage LOW
        client.publish(getOutTopic().c_str(), "GPIO2 set to LOW");
      } 
}
```

Comment: What is the output of the for-loop when the payload is 11? Also, you should put a separator to differentiate payload[0] from payload[1] in the for-loop.

Comment: The forloop is showing the payload properly.

Comment: Output your `payload` data once more after the first `if / elseif`. I have a feeling that your `client.publish()` destroys your `payload` pointer? If it outputted `11` after the first `for` loop, I see no reason in the code why the second `if/else` would not fire. Can you also remove all `client.publish()` calls and just look at the GPIO output pins with LEDs?

Comment: Hi Maximillian, you are absolutely right. I've fixed the issue by saving the payload to another variable, so that the payload buffer is not destroyed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The client.publish destroys the payload buffer. So I had to catch the payloads into new variables to overcome the problem.

```
 void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
      char p0 = (char)payload[0];
      char p1 = (char)payload[1];
      Serial.print("Message arrived [");
      Serial.print(topic);
      Serial.print("] ");
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
      }

       //Set GPIO0 to HIGH or LOW on first character received in message
      if (p0 == '1') {
        digitalWrite(GPIO0, HIGH);   // Turn the relay on
        client.publish(getOutTopic().c_str(), "GPIO0 set to HIGH");
      } else if (p0 == '0') {
        digitalWrite(GPIO0, LOW);  // Turn the relay off
        client.publish(getOutTopic().c_str(), "GPIO0 set to LOW");
      }

      //Set GPIO2 to HIGH or LOW on first character received in message
      if (p1 == '1') {
        digitalWrite(GPIO2, HIGH);   // turn LED off. With High it is inactive  on the ESP-01)
        client.publish(getOutTopic().c_str(), "GPIO2 set to HIGH");
      } else if (p1 == '0') {
        digitalWrite(GPIO2, LOW);  // Turn the LED on by making the voltage LOW
        client.publish(getOutTopic().c_str(), "GPIO2 set to LOW");
      } 
}
```